# Lose focus of Bootstrap button using jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

It seems that Bootstrap dropdown buttons stay focused after clicking them.

My use case is incompatible with that,

- The user is expected to hit 'SPACE' key after clicking on the button,
  in order to trigger something irrelevant with the button.
- The issue is that the button stays focused, so pressing SPACE
  activates the button.

I'm looking to lose focus on the button using jQuery

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/5911/),

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="hero-unit">
      <!-- Split button -->
    <div id="tools_fileMenu">
   <!-- Trace Image Dropdown -->
     <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" >Trace Image</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <span class="caret"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
       <li><input type="file" id="tool-placeImageFileDropdown" name="tool-placeImageFileDropdown[]" multiple/></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"  id="tool-placeImageUrlDropdown" >External URL</a></li>
       <li class="divider"></li>
       <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
</diV>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into `.blur()`: http://api.jquery.com/blur/

> To trigger the event programmatically, apply .blur() without an argument:

```
$( "#other" ).click(function() {
    $( "#target" ).blur();
});
```